# Get all the rows referencing (via foreign keys) a particular row in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

This seems so simple, but I haven't been able to find an answer to this question.

**What do I want?** A master table with rows that delete themselves whenever they are not referenced (via foreign keys) anymore. The solution may or may not be specific to PostgreSql.

**How?** One of my approaches to solving this problem (actually, the only approach so far) involves the following: For every table that references this master table, on `UPDATE` or `DELETE` of a row, to check for the referenced row in master, how many other other rows still refer to the referenced row. If it drops down to zero, then I delete that row in master as well.

(If you have a better idea, I'd like to know!)

**In detail:**
I have one master table referenced by many others

```
CREATE TABLE master (
  id serial primary key,
  name text unique not null
);
```

All the other tables have the same format generally:

```
CREATE TABLE other (
  ...
  master_id integer references master (id)
  ...
);
```

If one of these are not `NULL`, they refer to a row in `master`. If I go to this and try to delete it, I will get an error message, because it is already referred to:

```
ERROR:  update or delete on table "master" violates foreign key constraint "other_master_id_fkey" on table "other"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "other".
Time: 42.972 ms
```

Note that it doesn't take too long to figure this out even if I have many tables referencing `master`. How do I find this information out without having to raise an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

1) Add `reference_count` field to master table. Using triggers on detail tables increase the `reference count` whenever a row with this `master_id` is added. Decrease the count, when row gets deleted. When `reference_count` reaches 0 - delete the record.

2) Use `pg_constraint` table (details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html)) to get the list of referencing tables and create a dynamic SQL query.

3) Create triggers on every detail table, that deletes `master_id` in main table. Silence error messages with `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END`.

Comment: The reference count is indeed the only sane way. (after rereading the question) Personally I would never use it though (since it will complicate and slow down every operation), instead I would periodically clean up the unreferenced rows from the master table.

Comment: Suggestion 3. seems the least clean, but also the easiest. Is there a performance (or any other) penalty for using this kind of behavior. Is it frowned upon for being *hackish* or anything?

Comment: PostgreSql has to get the information I am looking for somewhere (otherwise it couldn't enforce the foreign key constraints). How does PostgreSql do it then? With internal reference counting? Considering the short runtime, I can hardly see that it would scan all the tables.

Comment: @cassava The third suggestion is indeed a hack. I don't know exactly how PostgreSQL gets the information for reference checking. My guess - simple table or index scans. Maybe with some internal magic to speed it up.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone wants a real count of rows in all other tables that reference a given master row, here is some PL/pgSQL. Note that this works in plain case with single column constraints. It gets more involved for multi-column constraints.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_references(master regclass, pkey_value integer,
    OUT "table" regclass, OUT count integer)
    RETURNS SETOF record 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
declare
  x record;           -- constraint info for each table in question that references master
  sql text;           -- temporary buffer
begin
  for x in
    select conrelid, attname
    from pg_constraint
    join pg_attribute on conrelid=attrelid and attnum=conkey[1]
    where contype='f' and confrelid=master
      and confkey=( -- here we assume that FK references master's PK
        select conkey
        from pg_constraint
        where conrelid=master and contype='p'
      )
  loop
    "table" = x.conrelid;
    sql = format('select count(*) from only %s where %I=$1', "table", x.attname);
    execute sql into "count" using pkey_value;
    return next;
  end loop;
end
$BODY$;
```

Then use it like

```
select * from count_references('master', 1) where count>0
```

This will return a list of tables that have references to master table with id=1.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM master ma
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM other ot
    WHERE ot.master_id = ma.id
    );
```

Or, the other way round:

```
SELECT * 
FROM other ot
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *    
    FROM master ma
    WHERE ot.master_id = ma.id
    );
```

SO if you want to update (or delete) only the rows in master that are not referenced by `other`, you could:

```
UPDATE master ma
SET id = 1000+id
  , name = 'blue'
WHERE name = 'green'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM other ot
    WHERE ot.master_id = ma.id
    );
```

Comment: I need the behavior for an indeterminate amount of referencing tables. So `other` is not the only other table! ;-)

Comment: If you need the deletes to be instantanious, the reference count+ triggers (Igor's answer) is the only way. If you could postpone the deletes to a periodic clean-up, you could query the catalogs to find the referencing tables and build a (dynamic) query from that.