# Is there any way to tell if a database row has constraints?

Tags: sql, perl, postgresql, dbi

I'm using Perl DBI with PostgreSQL, and my users will be deleting rows from a table, some of which can't be deleted because of foreign key constraints, which is fine, but I want a way to mark those rows on the front end so that it's known which rows have constraints before trying to delete them.  Right now, a user would just hit "delete" and would either get an error or have the row deleted.

Comment: And that is exactly the intention of constraints. Constraints exist because a data model has to be _imposed_ one way or the other. Just "hitting delete" because you want to delete some record does not make sense. Ergo: the app should be aware of the data model. For example: if you try to "delete" a person and a marriage-record for that person exists, what should happen to the marriage record?

Comment: @wildplasser, I understand why constraints exist.  My point is, I don't want to show a "delete user" button if it wouldn't work anyway.  I only want it to show for users that don't have any constraints.  But I don't know how other than to try to delete it and see if it returns an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgres: SQL to list table foreign keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152260/postgres-sql-to-list-table-foreign-keys)

Comment: Does your car have an "eject wheel" button? (maybe four of them)

Comment: @wildplasser Not sure I follow, seems like OP is asking how to find the constraints so that users don't even see the option to perform tasks they are restricted from doing.

Comment: IMHO the app should have an intimate relation with the database and the data model. This could be implemented by (application-)catalogs, but the app should be aware of the model. One way or the other. In any case "delete the record" is not an option. If _it_ is an intended operation, it should be implemented. One way or th other.

Comment: @GoatCO: there is a hidden "contract" beween the DB and the app. "finding the constraints" is (genearally) not the way to impose the contract.

Comment: @wildplasser, I actually don't care what the constraints are, I just want a boolean answer (either "yes this record can be deleted" or "no it cannot be deleted").

Comment: "I actually don't care if a wheel can be ejected. I just want to know: can this wheel be ejected?"

Comment: Ok, you don't understand the question at all I guess.

Comment: It seems that you want to do [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357121/postgresql-get-all-the-rows-referencing-via-foreign-keys-a-particular-row-in). But normally, your app should know about all the constraints and you should check them explicitly like wildplasser tried to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out on my own.  For anyone in a similar situation, you can turn on transactions

```
$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;
```

And then try to delete the row, like this for example…

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM auth_users WHERE username = ?");
$sth->execute($username);
```

And then check for an error...

```
if ( $sth->err ) { print "CAN'T be deleted.";}
else { print "CAN be deleted.";}
```

And then just roll back to not commit to the delete in case it could be deleted…

```
$dbh->rollback;
```

This is what works for me.  If anyone has any better ideas, or some concerns with this method, feel free to share.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not terribly familiar with PostgreSQL, but I believe you can use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.table_constraints 
WHERE table_name = 'YourTable'
```

Update- Looks like a solid answer here:
[Postgres: SQL to list table foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152260/postgres-sql-to-list-table-foreign-keys)

Comment: Yes and something similar in other databases.

Comment: I tried that and it only tells me about internal constraints (primary key column and unique columns).  Nothing about foreign keys.

Comment: I copy/pasted the SQL statement from the link you provided, only changing the table name and it doesn't return anything.  Am I supposed to change something else?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed That could mean that there are no foreign keys on the table you're looking at, does it return anything if you just use: `WHERE tc.table_name='mytable';`?

Comment: There's definitely constraints.  It's a users table and if I try to delete a user who.. made a comment (or anything from a slew of other different site activities), it returns an SQL foreign key constraint error.  And do you mean changing WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND tc.table_name='auth_users' to WHERE tc.table_name='auth_users'?  I made that change and got the same results as your original comment (primary key column and unique columns).

Comment: Sadly I know very little about PostgreSQL and don't have a sandbox instance to play with, hopefully someone else can weigh in.